# How to compare and substitute strings in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database, string-comparison, string-substitution

Trying to build a barebones concept in Ruby on Rails that will take a string, map each individual word in this string, compare it and then substitute the word if it matches predefined strings in related databases.

For example: User inputs in text field "What does lol and brb mean?" Hits Submit button. The action gives back the same text with "lol" and "brb" changed to "laughing out loud" and "be right back".

So far I have a Post model & table for the User input that stores the string in the database.

I have an Acronym model & table that has "lol" and "brb" stored in database with a foreign key reference to Acronym_Translate model & table that has "laughing out loud" and "be right back" referenced to "lol" and "brb", respectively.

How would I connect the Post model/table to the Acronym model/table in order to compare the strings in Post and substitute with strings from Acronym model/table? And what command could achieve such function? Would gsub! method work here?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to connect the Post table to the Acronym table? This means that you would have to identify and keep a record of each instance of an acronym within a post.

You can do this using a many to many relation or if you want to store extra data about each acronym occurrence you should create a link table named AcronymPost and use a has many through relationship between Post and Acronym. When you parse a post value, and when you identify an acronym in the post, you would have to record this in the database and then use gsub to replace the post value with the acronym.

You can iterate through your table of acronyms and use (string).include? method to check if it occurs in the post. Finally, you could use a gsub command to replace the acronym with its translation.

Comment: Thank you hypern! Im going to consider your suggestions and try to implement them to get the desired results. Will update soon.